# Call C# extention method without accessing it's class name

Tags: c#

I have Extension method to get string values are empty or check length is 0

```
public static class ExExtentions
    {        
        public static bool IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero(this string value)
        {
            bool t = false;
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value != "" || value.Length > 0)
                {
                    t = true;
                }
            }
            catch { t = false; }
            return t;
        }
    }
```

It must be call like this `ExExtentions.IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero(textBox1.Text)`

**Image 1 (what I've done)**

[image: What I Have]

But I want to call like `string.IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero(textBox1.Text)` and VS intelliSense show as parameter like this image NOT `ref string value`

**Image 2 (what I want : calling with `string.` and parameter `string value` not `this string value`)**

[image: What I want]

**If I am wrong (don't get serious with my code in extension block) how `.net framework` done this  `string.IsNullOrEmptry(TextBox1.Text)` get work ? Can I implement similar thing ?**

Comment: Your extension method is no better than `!string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: [What's the problem?](http://ideone.com/BI9Rzc)

Comment: method IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero will be added automatically to class string.

Comment: Yes but why I cant access some thing like `string.IsEx_MyExtention`

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` is just a static method on the `String` class. You can add static methods to types you own, but there is no way to extend existing types with static methods as you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call an extension method on an **instance** of the extended type.

> Can I implement similar thing ?

No, your proposed syntax would require adding a `static` method to `class String` but that's not an option.

You can use an extension method as if it were a member:

```
string s = null;
if (s.IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero()) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you give some example Or I want `string.IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero("some string")` but it's work as 
`"".IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero()`;

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call it like that then it shouldn't be an extension method. Extension methods are called on an instance of the extended class, in your case it would be like this.

```
textBox1.Text.IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero()
```

Comment: I want to use with string.MyExtention("any String values")

Comment: @Jimmer That's not possible. If you want to use like that, use your class name. I.e `ExExtentions.MyExtention("Whatever")`

Comment: This is work `"".IsEx_NotNullOrEmptyOrLenZero();` but it's not I want

Comment: `"".IsExWhaterver()` works because then you have an instance of a string that you call it on. Calling `string.IsExWhatever()` would need you to add a method to `System.String` but since that class is sealed you are out of luck.